# The method 'map' was called on null

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am still a beginner and while writing some simple app with dart , this problem appeared , the vs code studio does not show any errors within the code but the app won't run on the device and shows a red screen with this written :
NoSuchMethodError
The method 'map' was called on null.
Receiver: null
 Tried calling: map(Closure: (String) => Answer)

.....
here is the code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './questions.dart';
import './Answer.dart';

//void main() {
//runApp(MyCoolApp());
//}

void main() => runApp(
    MyCoolApp()); 

class MyCoolApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _MyCoolAppState();
  }
}

class _MyCoolAppState extends State<MyCoolApp> {
  var _questionsIndex = 0;

  void _answerQuestions() {
    setState(() {
      _questionsIndex = _questionsIndex + 1;
    });

    print(_questionsIndex);
  }

  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const questions = const [
      {
        'questionText': 'what is your favorite animal?',
        'asnwers': ['Black', 'White', 'Green', 'yellow'],
      },
      {
        'questionText': 'what is your favorite food?l?',
        'asnwers': ['MONKEY', 'LION', 'ELEPHANT', 'GIRAFFE'],
      },
      {
        'questionText': 'what is your favorite music genre?',
        'answers': ['ROCK', 'CLASSIC', 'JAZZ', 'COUNTRY']
      }
    ];
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            '7AMADA APP',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Questions(
              questions.elementAt(_questionsIndex)['questionText'],
            ),
            ...(questions.elementAt(_questionsIndex)['answers'] as List<String>)
                .map((answer) {
              return Answer(_answerQuestions, answer);
            }).toList()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: missed spelled word  "a**sn**wers" "a**ns**wers"

Comment: True, as @MohamedElrashid said you have misspelled the word answers, but you will also face an issue because you don't have a stop condition for incrementing the `_questionIndex`.. that will give you another error once you reach question number 3 and invoke the method.
One way of solving this is to put the condition for when the index is equal to length - 1 stop calling the method and pass the size of `questions` `List` as a parameter.